# ngTagsInput - close autocomplete list after selecting a tag

Tags: jquery, angularjs, cordova, angularjs-directive, ng-tags-input

I have the ngTagsInput directive set up as follows:

```
 <tags-input ng-model="controller.myTags" 
   replace-spaces-with-dashes="false">
   <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"
     min-length="0"
     load-on-empty="true"
     load-on-focus="true">
   </auto-complete>
 </tags-input>
```

The autocomplete list will show whenever a user selects the input area which is fine.  However, I would like the list to hide whenever a user has selected a tag from the autocomplete list.  Currently the list will still show after the user has selected a tag.

If I remove load-on-empty, the list will not show whenever in the input is in focus.

Comment: Had any luck? facing the same problem.